# ¿Cómo eliminar espacio blanco en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estimados soy nuevo en esto de mysql y estoy arreglando un reporte que es generado en pdf, pero el cual me deja un gran espacio a continuación les dejo el código y la imagen de como queda, y yo quiero que se vean juntos sin ningún espacio, aclaro que no puedo poner los datos en la imagen porque son privados pero del 1 al 4 son el problema

```
case "D":   
                            $consulta="call sem_psel_cons_pagos_exam('".$ddlProc."',
                            ".$txtRutMed."','".$ddlPrev."',
                            null,
                            '".$ddlEPag."',
                            '".$txtFechaIni."','".$txtFechaFin."',
                            '".$ddlTipo."')";
                            $result=mysqli_query($link,$consulta);  
                            $i = 0; $total = 0; $totcopago = 0;
                            $elfolio = 0; $elnropago = 0;
                            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
                                $contenido .= '<tr>';
                                if ($elfolio <> $row->numero) {
                                    $contenido .= '<td>'.($i+1).'</td>';
                                    $contenido .= '<td>'.$row->paciente.' (' .$row->rut. ')</td>';
                                    $contenido .= '<td>'.$row->fecha.'</td>';
                                    $contenido .= '<td>'.$row->folio.'</td>';
                                    $contenido .= '<td>'.$row->nompago.'</td>';
                                    $contenido .= '<td>'.$row->número.'</td>';
                                    $contenido .= '<td style="text-align:right;">'.number_format($row->monto, 0, ',', '.')  .'</td>';
                                    $contenido .= '<td style="text-align:right;">'.number_format($row->copago, 0, ',', '.') .'</td>';
                                    $contenido .= '<td>'.$row->descpago.'</td>';
                                    $elfolio =  $row->numero;
                                    $i+=1;
                                } else {
                                    $contenido .= '<td colspan="9"></td>';
                                }
                                
                                if ($elnropago <> $row->numero){
                                    $total += $row->monto;
                                    $totcopago += $row->copago;
                                    $elnropago = $row->numero;
                                }
                                    $contenido .= '<td>'.$row->nombreexamen.'</td>';
                                $contenido .= '</tr>';
                            }
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                            mysqli_close($link);
                            break;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.